# Google Places API <input> not submitting form on enter

Tags: html, backbone.js, google-places-api

Problem:
Pressing *Enter* does not submit the `<form>`. The `<input>` is hooked up to *Google Places API*, and submit works if it's a plain `<input>` field.

HTML:

```
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="query" id="geocode_query" />
    <!-- Working without id attribute:
         <input type="text" name="query" />
    -->
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

Backbone (event: `"geocode:result #geocode_query": "doSomething"`):

```
setLocation: (event, result) ->
  @location = result
```

See anything wrong? Thanks so much!